# determine a web URL in Android browser history is accessed by WIFI or 3g internet

Tags: android, url, browser

Can we determine a web URL in Android browser history is accessed by WIFI or 3g internet ?
I m collecting a browser history and i need to determine by which mean the specific URL was accessed last time... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant see which url is access by which connectivity what you can do is get the time of access and from your app hear for intent like wifi on or 3g on match both time you get to know

Comment: how can i determine which time was 3g on and which time was wifi ?

Comment: you need to save time in table for switching on and off for intent been fired in sqlite then you can run query in bookmark uri according to time

Comment: but this thing makes it much complicated